# Unexpected intersects behavior between GeoSeries of Polygons and one of Points

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, geopandas

Given a dataset of geometries (`shapes.geojson`) and a dataset of points (`poi.geojson`), I would expect that all geometries visibly intersecting with the points in the below plot would be returned when performing an intersection with GeoPandas’ GeoSeries’ `intersects` method.

[image]

```
ax = shapes.plot(color='b')
poi.plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

But, when the action is performed, the below two geometries are the only two returned. Plotting the `poi.geojson` in red shows where the other missing geometries might have been returned.

[image]

```
ax = shapes[shapes.intersects(poi)].plot(color='b')
poi.plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

My hunch was that there was something irregular with the data that was causing this but my reviews have come up dry.

Full datasets available as in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/kuanb/ba29ea73dc5858822fa4121fd7446fad) (using these will replicate the plots).

Example subset to be kept here, that will also reproduce the issue:

POI:

```
['POINT (-75.742553 39.206201)',
 'POINT (-75.74302 39.20764)',
 'POINT (-75.70948 39.19225)',
 'POINT (-75.74267 39.19168)',
 'POINT (-75.74307 39.20648)',
 'POINT (-75.7098 39.19458)',
 'POINT (-75.74302 39.20764)',
 'POINT (-75.742344 39.202771)',
 'POINT (-75.74335000000001 39.20829)',
 'POINT (-75.72824 39.20797)',
 'POINT (-75.73072019999999 39.1857066)',
 'POINT (-75.73072019999999 39.1857066)',
 'POINT (-75.72963 39.18498)',
 'POINT (-75.71019 39.19135)',
 'POINT (-75.72824 39.20797)',
 'POINT (-75.710331 39.193604)',
 'POINT (-75.74302 39.20764)',
 'POINT (-75.730403 39.185359)',
 'POINT (-75.734275 39.210892)',
 'POINT (-75.73140100000001 39.1848839)',
 'POINT (-75.723707 39.189565)',
 'POINT (-75.734275 39.210892)']
```

Shapes:

```
['POLYGON ((-75.73580200000001 39.188298, -75.739127 39.186513, -75.739569 39.186804, -75.73967 39.186871, -75.740713 39.187578, -75.740769 39.18763, -75.740881 39.187736, -75.741124 39.187968, -75.74119399999999 39.188034, -75.7414 39.188331, -75.741562 39.18855, -75.741699 39.188767, -75.74171 39.188788, -75.74186899999999 39.189086, -75.742036 39.189502, -75.74259600000001 39.190997, -75.74296 39.191968, -75.744315 39.195443, -75.744816 39.196717, -75.745565 39.198621, -75.744911 39.198673, -75.74426 39.198725, -75.74408699999999 39.198854, -75.744304 39.199928, -75.744435 39.200571, -75.744246 39.200598, -75.74408200000001 39.200623, -75.74389600000001 39.200652, -75.74368200000001 39.200685, -75.743495 39.200715, -75.74284900000001 39.200772, -75.742559 39.200794, -75.742497 39.200799, -75.741827 39.200923, -75.741219 39.201056, -75.740942 39.201121, -75.740661 39.201187, -75.740301 39.201277, -75.73999999999999 39.201345, -75.739817 39.201417, -75.73978700000001 39.20143, -75.739559 39.201515, -75.739278 39.201647, -75.738964 39.201805, -75.73882399999999 39.201595, -75.738612 39.201386, -75.73857700000001 39.20132, -75.738563 39.20115, -75.73871800000001 39.200853, -75.738732 39.200793, -75.738739 39.200617, -75.738534 39.200364, -75.738011 39.199985, -75.737891 39.199887, -75.73780600000001 39.199744, -75.737792 39.199672, -75.73778 39.199539, -75.73777800000001 39.199513, -75.737848 39.198832, -75.73786800000001 39.198162, -75.738073 39.197722, -75.738044 39.197179, -75.738058 39.197107, -75.73820600000001 39.19686, -75.738277 39.196563, -75.738411 39.196311, -75.73846 39.196014, -75.738438 39.195794, -75.738283 39.195553, -75.737605 39.194932, -75.737442 39.19468, -75.73675 39.19396, -75.73645999999999 39.193719, -75.736439 39.193433, -75.73640399999999 39.193334, -75.73621300000001 39.193115, -75.736164 39.192961, -75.73621300000001 39.192862, -75.736474 39.192648, -75.73648799999999 39.192626, -75.73649500000001 39.192598, -75.736431 39.192477, -75.736375 39.192444, -75.736283 39.192412, -75.73612799999999 39.192412, -75.736093 39.192415, -75.736008 39.192423, -75.735958 39.192406, -75.735845 39.19234, -75.735789 39.192296, -75.735506 39.191989, -75.73496299999999 39.191605, -75.73487799999999 39.191511, -75.734842 39.191412, -75.734835 39.191357, -75.73487799999999 39.191099, -75.73480000000001 39.190951, -75.73465899999999 39.190885, -75.734087 39.190858, -75.73369099999999 39.190836, -75.733501 39.190798, -75.733367 39.190759, -75.73333100000001 39.190721, -75.733204 39.190435, -75.733119 39.190342, -75.732992 39.190298, -75.73239 39.19013, -75.73580200000001 39.188298))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.73577400000001 39.184377, -75.73653400000001 39.184871, -75.737371 39.185415, -75.73795 39.185738, -75.73814400000001 39.185866, -75.739127 39.186513, -75.73580200000001 39.188298, -75.73239 39.19013, -75.73304400000001 39.190669, -75.73061800000001 39.192283, -75.729434 39.190607, -75.729325 39.190206, -75.729044 39.188818, -75.72897500000001 39.188762, -75.72860799999999 39.188548, -75.728544 39.188498, -75.72846 39.188405, -75.728156 39.187883, -75.72799999999999 39.187471, -75.727947 39.187318, -75.729714 39.187132, -75.730301 39.187031, -75.730345 39.187014, -75.730417 39.186987, -75.730497 39.186948, -75.73055600000001 39.186905, -75.730593 39.186845, -75.730626 39.186615, -75.730704 39.185886, -75.73074200000001 39.185542, -75.730752 39.185232, -75.730773 39.184589, -75.730958 39.18455, -75.731129 39.184523, -75.731855 39.184409, -75.73212100000001 39.184353, -75.73220000000001 39.184338, -75.732337 39.184314, -75.732555 39.184264, -75.73286400000001 39.18418, -75.73287500000001 39.184178, -75.73299 39.184125, -75.733159 39.18404, -75.733276 39.183956, -75.733452 39.18385, -75.733614 39.183739, -75.733684 39.183682, -75.733767 39.183616, -75.73393900000001 39.183486, -75.73397900000001 39.183454, -75.73410199999999 39.183361, -75.734144 39.18333, -75.73428199999999 39.183408, -75.7355 39.184199, -75.73577400000001 39.184377))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.718181 39.190346, -75.718226 39.190534, -75.718594 39.191852, -75.718643 39.191923, -75.718813 39.192033, -75.719173 39.192094, -75.71954700000001 39.192192, -75.71987900000001 39.192352, -75.72014 39.192582, -75.720203 39.192675, -75.72050299999999 39.193205, -75.72057100000001 39.193324, -75.720839 39.193593, -75.72156699999999 39.194389, -75.72209599999999 39.194987, -75.722146 39.195059, -75.72248500000001 39.195767, -75.722718 39.196174, -75.72287300000001 39.1963, -75.70958899999999 39.191293, -75.709891 39.191258, -75.71025400000001 39.191218, -75.710802 39.191174, -75.711106 39.19115, -75.711218 39.191141, -75.71252200000001 39.191001, -75.713138 39.190936, -75.714904 39.190734, -75.716528 39.190561, -75.716768 39.19053, -75.718121 39.190359, -75.718181 39.190346))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.72287300000001 39.1963, -75.722718 39.196174, -75.72248500000001 39.195767, -75.722146 39.195059, -75.72209599999999 39.194987, -75.72156699999999 39.194389, -75.720839 39.193593, -75.72057100000001 39.193324, -75.72050299999999 39.193205, -75.720203 39.192675, -75.72014 39.192582, -75.71987900000001 39.192352, -75.71954700000001 39.192192, -75.719173 39.192094, -75.718813 39.192033, -75.718643 39.191923, -75.718594 39.191852, -75.718226 39.190534, -75.718181 39.190346, -75.718366 39.190306, -75.71871299999999 39.190234, -75.7189 39.190178, -75.718919 39.190171, -75.719098 39.190107, -75.719134 39.190093, -75.719453 39.189928, -75.719824 39.189698, -75.721204 39.188845, -75.72194399999999 39.18837, -75.72201099999999 39.188328, -75.72264199999999 39.187913, -75.722936 39.187716, -75.72297500000001 39.187691, -75.72321599999999 39.187523, -75.72342399999999 39.187344, -75.72358 39.18719, -75.72375099999999 39.187038, -75.724017 39.186804, -75.724116 39.186717, -75.72425800000001 39.186605, -75.72430199999999 39.18657, -75.72447 39.186444, -75.724701 39.186333, -75.72499500000001 39.186194, -75.725694 39.185899, -75.72673 39.185461, -75.726848 39.18543, -75.72701499999999 39.185373, -75.727126 39.185336, -75.727362 39.185264, -75.72775300000001 39.185157, -75.727818 39.185143, -75.727639 39.185801, -75.727738 39.186219, -75.727788 39.186362, -75.727767 39.186708, -75.72780899999999 39.186922, -75.727859 39.187065, -75.727947 39.187318, -75.72799999999999 39.187471, -75.728156 39.187883, -75.72846 39.188405, -75.728544 39.188498, -75.72860799999999 39.188548, -75.72897500000001 39.188762, -75.729044 39.188818, -75.729325 39.190206, -75.729434 39.190607, -75.73061800000001 39.192283, -75.73304400000001 39.190669, -75.73239 39.19013, -75.732992 39.190298, -75.733119 39.190342, -75.733204 39.190435, -75.73333100000001 39.190721, -75.733367 39.190759, -75.733501 39.190798, -75.73369099999999 39.190836, -75.734087 39.190858, -75.73465899999999 39.190885, -75.73480000000001 39.190951, -75.73487799999999 39.191099, -75.734835 39.191357, -75.734842 39.191412, -75.73487799999999 39.191511, -75.73496299999999 39.191605, -75.735506 39.191989, -75.735789 39.192296, -75.735845 39.19234, -75.735958 39.192406, -75.736008 39.192423, -75.736093 39.192415, -75.73612799999999 39.192412, -75.736283 39.192412, -75.736375 39.192444, -75.736431 39.192477, -75.73649500000001 39.192598, -75.73648799999999 39.192626, -75.736474 39.192648, -75.73621300000001 39.192862, -75.736164 39.192961, -75.73621300000001 39.193115, -75.73640399999999 39.193334, -75.736439 39.193433, -75.73645999999999 39.193719, -75.73675 39.19396, -75.737442 39.19468, -75.737605 39.194932, -75.738283 39.195553, -75.738438 39.195794, -75.73846 39.196014, -75.738411 39.196311, -75.738277 39.196563, -75.73820600000001 39.19686, -75.738058 39.197107, -75.738044 39.197179, -75.738073 39.197722, -75.73786800000001 39.198162, -75.737848 39.198832, -75.73777800000001 39.199513, -75.73778 39.199539, -75.737792 39.199672, -75.73780600000001 39.199744, -75.737891 39.199887, -75.738011 39.199985, -75.738534 39.200364, -75.738739 39.200617, -75.738732 39.200793, -75.73871800000001 39.200853, -75.738563 39.20115, -75.73857700000001 39.20132, -75.738612 39.201386, -75.73882399999999 39.201595, -75.738964 39.201805, -75.73890900000001 39.201833, -75.73858 39.202007, -75.738338 39.20214, -75.73824999999999 39.202189, -75.737526 39.202602, -75.736491 39.203202, -75.735878 39.203559, -75.73581799999999 39.203535, -75.73562 39.203491, -75.735507 39.203486, -75.73532400000001 39.203508, -75.73465400000001 39.203719, -75.733997 39.203926, -75.733806 39.203975, -75.73321300000001 39.204063, -75.73314999999999 39.20408, -75.732832 39.204245, -75.732218 39.204399, -75.731013 39.204767, -75.730729 39.204855, -75.730496 39.204839, -75.730178 39.204768, -75.730093 39.204735, -75.729811 39.204586, -75.729784 39.204557, -75.729703 39.204472, -75.729676 39.204444, -75.72949300000001 39.203883, -75.729337 39.202955, -75.72921599999999 39.202543, -75.729258 39.202131, -75.72928 39.20206, -75.729597 39.201521, -75.729682 39.201225, -75.729681 39.201148, -75.729653 39.201011, -75.729437 39.200625, -75.72941299999999 39.200582, -75.729342 39.200511, -75.729095 39.200308, -75.72872099999999 39.200033, -75.72813499999999 39.199654, -75.72636199999999 39.198979, -75.72553600000001 39.198436, -75.72519 39.198073, -75.725049 39.197826, -75.72492800000001 39.197436, -75.72466 39.197057, -75.724377 39.19675, -75.724194 39.196629, -75.72372799999999 39.19647, -75.723586 39.196437, -75.72305 39.196388, -75.722943 39.196335, -75.72287300000001 39.1963))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.70958899999999 39.191293, -75.72287300000001 39.1963, -75.722943 39.196335, -75.72305 39.196388, -75.723586 39.196437, -75.72372799999999 39.19647, -75.724194 39.196629, -75.724377 39.19675, -75.72466 39.197057, -75.72492800000001 39.197436, -75.725049 39.197826, -75.72519 39.198073, -75.72553600000001 39.198436, -75.72636199999999 39.198979, -75.72813499999999 39.199654, -75.72872099999999 39.200033, -75.729095 39.200308, -75.729342 39.200511, -75.72941299999999 39.200582, -75.729437 39.200625, -75.729653 39.201011, -75.729681 39.201148, -75.729682 39.201225, -75.729597 39.201521, -75.72928 39.20206, -75.729258 39.202131, -75.72921599999999 39.202543, -75.729337 39.202955, -75.72949300000001 39.203883, -75.729676 39.204444, -75.729281 39.204142, -75.72863099999999 39.203708, -75.728419 39.20362, -75.728313 39.203615, -75.72762899999999 39.203642, -75.72674600000001 39.203797, -75.726097 39.203978, -75.72579399999999 39.204033, -75.72568 39.204055, -75.724501 39.204341, -75.723358 39.204523, -75.72296900000001 39.204572, -75.722369 39.204605, -75.7216 39.204628, -75.721346 39.204622, -75.720809 39.204518, -75.72007499999999 39.204287, -75.71960199999999 39.204205, -75.71827399999999 39.204162, -75.717872 39.204189, -75.717392 39.204266, -75.71716600000001 39.204299, -75.716933 39.204288, -75.71686200000001 39.204244, -75.716679 39.204091, -75.71629 39.203734, -75.71598 39.203503, -75.716008 39.203305, -75.715951 39.203185, -75.715294 39.202613, -75.71499799999999 39.2023, -75.71492000000001 39.202256, -75.714793 39.202229, -75.714609 39.202174, -75.714372 39.202043, -75.714151 39.201922, -75.714037 39.20174, -75.713854 39.201301, -75.71375500000001 39.201164, -75.71358499999999 39.201059, -75.713268 39.200977, -75.713134 39.2009, -75.712632 39.200576, -75.711347 39.200533, -75.711016 39.200505, -75.71091 39.200489, -75.71085600000001 39.200461, -75.710886 39.20022, -75.71099700000001 39.199436, -75.71102500000001 39.199202, -75.711023 39.198954, -75.711015 39.198794, -75.710992 39.198631, -75.71098600000001 39.198605, -75.71083400000001 39.197926, -75.71016299999999 39.195421, -75.709985 39.194788, -75.70979699999999 39.193841, -75.709699 39.193437, -75.70966799999999 39.193159, -75.709647 39.192967, -75.70962400000001 39.192378, -75.70961 39.191867, -75.709603 39.191594, -75.70958899999999 39.191293))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.73244 39.214083, -75.730515 39.213414, -75.72474 39.211409, -75.722815 39.210741, -75.723426 39.210463, -75.72396999999999 39.210199, -75.724549 39.209892, -75.72523099999999 39.209502, -75.725463 39.209373, -75.726288 39.208918, -75.72690900000001 39.208565, -75.727627 39.208158, -75.72804499999999 39.207926, -75.72817000000001 39.207857, -75.730197 39.20674, -75.733288 39.205037, -75.734129 39.204574, -75.735878 39.203559, -75.73618500000001 39.203678, -75.736602 39.203815, -75.736672 39.203829, -75.736983 39.203891, -75.738134 39.20394, -75.738452 39.203891, -75.738995 39.203748, -75.73916199999999 39.203715, -75.73968000000001 39.203616, -75.73999000000001 39.203571, -75.74020899999999 39.203654, -75.740647 39.203758, -75.740686 39.203778, -75.740922 39.203901, -75.74142399999999 39.204274, -75.74153 39.204323, -75.74263000000001 39.204744, -75.74303399999999 39.204899, -75.743154 39.204932, -75.743326 39.204937, -75.743257 39.205981, -75.743229 39.206427, -75.743171 39.207816, -75.743165 39.207962, -75.743098 39.209117, -75.743039 39.210163, -75.743005 39.210749, -75.74294399999999 39.211073, -75.742897 39.211246, -75.74276 39.211583, -75.74274800000001 39.211615, -75.741614 39.214085, -75.74100900000001 39.215526, -75.740983 39.215586, -75.740844 39.215917, -75.740392 39.216922, -75.738801 39.216354, -75.73403 39.21465, -75.73244 39.214083))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.710657 39.202046, -75.710696 39.201728, -75.71081599999999 39.200777, -75.71085600000001 39.200461, -75.71091 39.200489, -75.711016 39.200505, -75.711347 39.200533, -75.712632 39.200576, -75.713134 39.2009, -75.713268 39.200977, -75.71358499999999 39.201059, -75.71375500000001 39.201164, -75.713854 39.201301, -75.714037 39.20174, -75.714151 39.201922, -75.714372 39.202043, -75.714609 39.202174, -75.714793 39.202229, -75.71492000000001 39.202256, -75.71499799999999 39.2023, -75.715294 39.202613, -75.715951 39.203185, -75.716008 39.203305, -75.71598 39.203503, -75.71629 39.203734, -75.716679 39.204091, -75.71686200000001 39.204244, -75.716933 39.204288, -75.71716600000001 39.204299, -75.717392 39.204266, -75.717872 39.204189, -75.71827399999999 39.204162, -75.71960199999999 39.204205, -75.72007499999999 39.204287, -75.720809 39.204518, -75.721346 39.204622, -75.7216 39.204628, -75.722369 39.204605, -75.72296900000001 39.204572, -75.723358 39.204523, -75.724501 39.204341, -75.72568 39.204055, -75.72579399999999 39.204033, -75.726097 39.203978, -75.72674600000001 39.203797, -75.72762899999999 39.203642, -75.728313 39.203615, -75.728419 39.20362, -75.72863099999999 39.203708, -75.729281 39.204142, -75.729676 39.204444, -75.729703 39.204472, -75.729784 39.204557, -75.729811 39.204586, -75.730093 39.204735, -75.730178 39.204768, -75.730496 39.204839, -75.730729 39.204855, -75.731013 39.204767, -75.732218 39.204399, -75.732832 39.204245, -75.73314999999999 39.20408, -75.73321300000001 39.204063, -75.733806 39.203975, -75.733997 39.203926, -75.73465400000001 39.203719, -75.73532400000001 39.203508, -75.735507 39.203486, -75.73562 39.203491, -75.73581799999999 39.203535, -75.735878 39.203559, -75.734129 39.204574, -75.733288 39.205037, -75.730197 39.20674, -75.72817000000001 39.207857, -75.72804499999999 39.207926, -75.727627 39.208158, -75.72690900000001 39.208565, -75.726288 39.208918, -75.725463 39.209373, -75.72523099999999 39.209502, -75.724549 39.209892, -75.72396999999999 39.210199, -75.723426 39.210463, -75.722815 39.210741, -75.72192099999999 39.210458, -75.721829 39.210429, -75.71924199999999 39.20961, -75.718349 39.209328, -75.71829200000001 39.209244, -75.718124 39.208992, -75.718068 39.208909, -75.71773399999999 39.208412, -75.717641 39.208262, -75.717511 39.20808, -75.71740800000001 39.207966, -75.71730100000001 39.207886, -75.717259 39.207854, -75.717207 39.207851, -75.71713200000001 39.207813, -75.717033 39.207783, -75.716909 39.207728, -75.71651799999999 39.207609, -75.71639399999999 39.207578, -75.715901 39.207458, -75.714135 39.206993, -75.71284 39.206636, -75.712093 39.206369, -75.711579 39.206173, -75.71121599999999 39.206013, -75.710753 39.205777, -75.710537 39.205593, -75.71043 39.205477, -75.710363 39.205363, -75.710303 39.205189, -75.710297 39.205134, -75.710296 39.205116, -75.710339 39.20475, -75.710379 39.20425, -75.71048 39.203413, -75.710556 39.202901, -75.710576 39.202729, -75.71063599999999 39.202217, -75.710657 39.202046))',
 'POLYGON ((-75.738964 39.201805, -75.73919100000001 39.202149, -75.73932600000001 39.202352, -75.739538 39.202665, -75.739754 39.203242, -75.739785 39.203324, -75.73984900000001 39.203445, -75.73999000000001 39.203571, -75.73968000000001 39.203616, -75.73916199999999 39.203715, -75.738995 39.203748, -75.738452 39.203891, -75.738134 39.20394, -75.736983 39.203891, -75.736672 39.203829, -75.736602 39.203815, -75.73618500000001 39.203678, -75.735878 39.203559, -75.736491 39.203202, -75.737526 39.202602, -75.73824999999999 39.202189, -75.738338 39.20214, -75.73858 39.202007, -75.73890900000001 39.201833, -75.738964 39.201805))']
```

Should this be relevant, I have attempted this on both GeoPandas 0.2.1 and 0.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should not have been comparing with another GeoSeries but instead with a single Shapely object. One way to accomplish what I desired is through the following method:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

single_shapely_compare = MultiPoint(poi_fresh.geometry)
ax = subset_fresh[subset_fresh.intersects(single_shapely_compare)].plot(color='b')
poi_fresh.plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

This would have generated the following plot, which is the desired/expected result:
[image]